# Why WebClient Exceptions can be caught by WebException while its not descendant of WebRequest and WebResponse?

Tags: c#

based on microsoft article as bellow

> The WebException class is thrown by classes descended from WebRequest
>   and WebResponse

but `Webclient` is not a descendant of those abstract class and it's exception could be caught by `WebException` as we used this way many times in our projects.

actually `WebClient` is an independent abstract class.

so should  we come to a conclusion that this article does not imply for `WebClient`?

you can read microsoft article through link below

[Microsoft WebException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Is your question, essentially, why is documentation sometimes inaccurate or out of date?

Comment: `WebClient` wraps `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` which *do* derive from `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`.

Comment: That said - why are you using `WebClient` in 2019? You should be using `HttpClient`.

Comment: There is no limitation as to which class can throw this exception, you can write code in your own project that throws it. My guess is that it was *intended* to be for only those classes but that someone decided that this exception was a good fit also for WebClient. WebClient is a heavy user of WebRequest and WebResponse so I don't see a problem here. The documentation is just (slightly) inaccurate. Having said that, shouldn't you be using HttpClient instead?

Answer (score -1):

WebClient is so old and also it can't provide some new feature of the new version of dot net.